# How can Bash process substitution be used to have a variable define a program's configuration instead of a file?

Tags: bash, configuration, process, substitution, tmux

I want to run a program (`tmux`) with a configuration that is set in a Bash variable instead of a file. The standard way to load a configuration from a file for `tmux` is as follows:

```
tmux -f test.conf attach
```

I have a configuration specified in Bash variable `configurationTmux`:

```
IFS= read -d '' configurationTmux << "EOF"
set -g set-remain-on-exit on
new -s "STANDARD INTERFACE"
set-option -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind - split-window -v
bind | split-window -h
## colours
set-option -g window-status-current-bg yellow
set-option -g pane-active-border-fg yellow
set -g status-fg black
set -g status-bg '#FEFE0A'
set -g message-fg black
set -g message-bg '#FEFE0A'
set -g message-command-fg black
set -g message-command-bg '#FEFE0A'
set-option -g mode-keys vi
set -g history-limit 5000
## mouse mode
set -g mode-mouse on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on # resize panes with mouse (drag borders)
## status
set-option -g status-interval 1
set-option -g status-left-length 20
set-option -g status-left ''
set-option -g status-right '%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S '
## run programs in panes
# split left-right
split-window -h
# split left up
select-pane -t 0
split-window -v
select-pane -t 0
split-window -v
select-pane -t 0
split-window -v
select-pane -t 0
send-keys 'ranger' Enter
select-pane -t 2
send-keys 'htop' Enter
select-pane -t 3
send-keys 'elinks http://arxiv.org/list/hep-ph/new' Enter
select-pane -t 4
send-keys 'vi' Enter
set -g set-remain-on-exit off
EOF
```

I have tried using this variable instead of a file in the following way:

```
tmux -f <(${configurationTmux}) attach
```

This results in the following error:

```
bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
no sessions
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Process substitution runs a process. You are giving it a shell variable which it is interpreting as a script to run (hence the `set` error since shell `set` doesn't understand `-g` as an argument).

You need your string returned as output from the process substitution. `<$(echo "$configurationTmux")`

That being said if tmux expects to be able to seek or do anything else fancy around the config file this will not work.

---

In the general case something like the following can also be used (assuming `/dev/stdin` exists or a similar entry point can be found `/proc/self/fd/0` or some-such) and that doing this doesn't harm subsequently spawned processes that will/may inherit standard input (so not useful in the `tmux` case apparently, thanks @chepner).

You can probably also do something like `echo "$configurationTmux" | tmux -f /dev/stdin attach`.

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. Thank you very much for your help on that!

Comment: `/dev/stdin` will only work if the file system has such an entry. (`bash` only treats it specially if used with a redirection.) The bigger problem with the pipe, though, is that all the shells started by `tmux` inherit *their* standard input from `tmux`, so that approach won't work.