# Put the "RSA PRIVATE KEY" in the shh command directly

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

In general, if we want to access the remote server, we need to download the key, "token.pem".
Put the key to the specific path, "$HOME/token.pem".
Then use `chmod 400 $HOME/token.pem` and `ssh -i $HOME/token.pem user@hostname` for access.

Now, I want to write the shell script, "connection.sh".
In this script, I want to write look like
`ssh "RSA PRIVATE KEY" user@hostname` in the "connection.sh" file.
Then I can use "sh connection.sh" to access my server without "-i".

How to modified the code in the shell script?

Comment: "shell" meaning `sh`? In general, the only reasonably-likely way to do this without creating a temporary file or named pipe on disk is going to require an extended shell (such as bash); and even that will require that your ssh implementation read the file only once, front-to-back -- which isn't typically a documented guarantee.

Comment: Anyhow -- _if_ this is possible, it's presumably a duplicate of [How can bash process substitution be used to have a variable define a program's configuration instead of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220854/how-can-bash-process-substitution-be-used-to-have-a-variable-define-a-programs). Roughly: `ssh -i <(echo "$token") ...` -- but that's by no means sure to work, _especially_ when a program is trying to do security checks on the file storing the token; sometimes competing design goals work against you.

Comment: (in general, `sh connection.sh` is a bad idea, because it doesn't let `connection.sh` choose its shell but forces `sh`, which has a very minimal set of features; instead, write your `connection` script to where it's an executable that starts with a shebang indicating what interpreter it should be run with, and start it as `./connection` -- that way you can rewrite it in the future to use an interpreter other than `sh` if you need new/different features, and the command used to start it doesn't need to change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already want to write a shell script, why not use it in he same way like the work description?

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
curl <uri to token.pem> -o $HOME/token.pem
chmod 400 $HOME/token.pem
ssh -i $HOME/token.pem user@hostname
```